# safari IOS menu bar conflicts with buttons in lower 10% of the screen

Tags: ios, safari, development, html

I am building a web-portal which has to be functional and pretty on multiple platforms.
One of the platforms is IOS Safari, and this is were I encountered a problem.
In my code I align two floating buttons to the bottom of a div with a width and height of 100%
This all works fine and my buttons show up exactly like they are supposed to on the bottom of the page.
However when I click the buttons the compact view from mobile safari switches to full view and my buttons are hidden behind the bottom nav bar!

Is it normal behavior for safari mobile to show the expanded menu when the user taps in the bottom 10% of the screen? 
How can I avoid this?

In this gif you can see the problem on the IOS simulator:
[image: example]
As you can see the problem only occurs when a button is in the lower 10% of the view. This is just a normal button, My code was triple checked by several developers and it has no errors.

Comment: If you list your code snippet, flag this and we can migrate to stack overflow...

Comment: I've created bug for Safari, please comment there: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194235

Comment: Still nobody has fixed this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal behavior in Mobile Safari, tapping at the bottom will display the various browser options and scroll the web page up accordingly. Web page functionality stays the same though, so the user can still tap on the button after it scrolled to access whatever functionality it has.

Comment: Thanks Patrix, I know this is normal, but is there a way to override this behavior through html, css or js? I have already posted this question on stack overflow but since it is something related to apple maybe ask-different will know a way

Comment: StackOverflow (or even an SE site where web developers hang out) is better for this kind of thing than AD (which is focused on end user issues). As accessing browser controls is somehow essential for the user I doubt whether there is a way to avoid the behavior though.

Comment: link to the stack overflow q&a for this?

Comment: what's the actual size of this in pixels? Can't find it anywhere... 56px isn't enough. What's the name of this "dead zone"?

Answer (score 9):

I think I may have found an answer. Setting your content to have the following styles:

- `height: 100%` (allows content to fill the viewport and go beyond the bottom)
- `overflow-y: scroll` (allows you to scroll below the viewport; the default value is `visible`)
- `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` (to smooth any scroll behavior)

appears to force the iOS menu in Safari to always appear. That way, button clicks will actually work instead of opening up the Safari menu. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sure, this does works, but not all sites can tolerate setting `overflow-y: scroll` on their main content area.  This hack has side effects that will affect all it's children elements.  To put it more correctly, these css properties directly effect all children elements and forcing the safari menu to show is actually the side effect.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tried tapping towards bottom of screen yet but at least 10% of my design isn't being covered up by Safari's obnoxious menu bar.

To add to this, you need to give every containing element `height: 100%` as well.

For a company that makes a lot of their money from mobile devices their mobile web experience is horrible.

Comment: @corysimmons As we have seen with WebRTC and still see with [Push API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api), Apple is trying to get developers to create a native app if you want significantly more than just display a simple page.